# Can we use appium doctor to verify settings on windows ?

Tags: appium

I read somewhere we can use appium doctor to verify appium settings?

Can we use it on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to run [these commands](https://github.com/appium/appium-doctor) on windows too.

it uses [appium-support](https://github.com/appium/appium-support/blob/master/lib/system.js) to check the SO, and theres windows on the list

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use appium doctor to verify setting on windows and appium doctor is by default for ios